# Read data from excel file inside file cabinet

Tags: netsuite

What I want is to read excel file inside netsuite File Cabinet.
On nlapiLoadFile i cant able to read excel file. I used getValue() but result will be in another format.
its show something like dW5kZWZpbm..
How to get data help me out.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the solution..
just to use
var temp = nlapiDecrypt(somestring,'base64');